# Autonegotiated link speed different between devices using exact same cable

Tags: networking, ethernet, speed, gigabit-ethernet

looked far and wide on the internet but could not find a solution to this totally ridiculous networking issue I'm having. Using an all-wired system with a Pace 5268ac with Gigabit internet from AT&T. Pace is connected to Windows 8.1 PC through the wall via wall jacks, I'm using shielded Cat6A cables everywhere but have no idea what is in the wall. For months I've been using this (1000mb) setup perfectly.

Got back from a trip and the PC is auto-negotiating 100mbps with no known changes to hardware or firmware (as shown in the router settings and in Device Manager). For a while restarting the PC and Pace would solve it, but would only be a few hours or less before it would drop down to 100mbps. Now, never seems to get into full 1000mbps mode. Cable/NIC issue right? Here's where it gets weird: the same exact cable (a known-good, and many other testers), plugged into the same wall, then into a Mac 10.13 with a Thunderbolt ethernet adapter, gets the full 1000mbps and has maintained that speed for 24+ hours, enough to satisfy me that it's not downshifting. Even weirder: same exact cable plugged into a totally different PC, a Windows 7 laptop, is capped at 100mbps!! This laptop, plugged directly into the router, sees the full 1000mbps connection correctly autonegotiate.

Clearly there is no physical problem in the wall as my Mac negotiates a perfect full-speed connection. What else could possibly be the issue here? I've tried setting manual speeds—just appears disconnected.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, during one of the moments where the PC was working normally, I ran all the tests in the Properties pane in the Device Manager.  Came back with all passes and said the network quality was very good.  Cable length of 19m which doesn't seem too long in total

Comment: You may be making inaccurate assumptions, or something is intermittent and you haven’t recognized the pattern yet. It’s definitely a cabling issue, as you have confirmed that by plugging directly in to the router and it works, and you’ve plugged the defective cabling in to two different computers and it has a problem. The information you’re getting from the Mac is not accurate because it is not confirmed by the other facts. Not all the wires in your cable are good. You can use a tester or you can try repunching the wires on the wall jacks. Or replacing them.

Comment: I'm certainly looking to challenge my assumptions but I guess I'm not sure which assumptions I'm making.  The speed on the Mac is confirmed by the Pace (showing 1 Gbps link speed, when having the issue it shows 100mbps), the Mac itself (Network -> Hardware -> showing 1000baseT, full-duplex, flow-control), and speedof.me which tests speed by actually downloading information and it shows well over 100mbps.  Happy to look into wall jacks if need be, but they are clearly working perfectly.

Comment: How are the pins in the problematic nic? They are bright and not bent right? Auto-negotiation does fail from time to time. What happens when you turn auto-negotiation off? And force 1000mbps. I would be willing to bet the difference is the problematic PC has a "green Ethernet feature". Green Ethernet determines the total length of the cable then adjusts power levels accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have ruled out the cable and the computers, the only thing left is the wiring in the wall.  While you can get gigabit speeds over small distances over non certified ethernet, there is no guarantee.  Since you dont know what is in the wall, it is safe to say it is not cat6 cables.  Sure they might run at gigabit speeds, but perhaps a nearby power line has a higher load and is causing interference, which is slowing down your network speed. Also, different NICs have different thresholds for autonegotiation.  It could just be your Windows machine's NIC is more sensitive.

You could invest in replacing the wiring in your walls, or use powerline ethernet adapters.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what I've ruled out because the Mac working perfectly seems like it would rule out issues in the wall.  I see what you're saying about different NIC's having different thresholds, but it's not like the network is struggling on my Mac.  It gets about the same network results plugged directly in and via the wall.  Also, for one of the brief windows where the PC was working properly, I did all the networks tests in the Device Manager Properties pane and they all came back passed/very good.  Cable length was 19m which doesn't seem to long

Comment: @keltari "perhaps a power line has a higher load and is causing interference" this is a fable that layer 2-7 guys seem to propigate. I think you need to read the difference between common-mode and differential-mode interference. Balanced cabling systems are immune to this type of interference well into the tens of MHZ